# How to make hashlinks look like directories

Tags: html

I have a website, anandchowdhary.com/, which is a single-page website; I have sections, like anandchowdhary.com#about and anandchowdhary.com/#contact, but I want the address bar to look like http://anandchowdhary.com/about or http://anandchowdhary.com/contact.

I Googled, and learnt that something like this can be done with htaccess, but I couldn't figure out how to go about it. Any help?

Comment: Anything from # onwards is never sent to the server and therefore .htaccess can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the URL after the page has been loaded using Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       // On click action
        window.history.pushState(null, "Title", "/new-url");
    });
```

This will change the URL without reloading.
And add the following for each link to htaccess for the reverse condition to work,

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/about/$ http://anandchowdhary.com/#about
```

Comment: Could you post some code snippets to show your implementation of this? I have used this before on numerous occasions.

Comment: @Shahil your suggestion just changes the displayed title, but the user must still initially go to /#whatever. If the user goes to /directory directly, they'll get a 404. They should use htaccess to add a redirect for that directory.